# Set php_value in htacces for sub-directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

since the .htaccess file in my Nextcloud instance is overwritten with every update, I thought a solution for having a PHP `memory_limit` of at least 512 MB was to set this in the htaccess of the directory my instance-directory (LIVE) is placed.

```
- root
-- .htaccess (my idea: Use this as configuration file for memory_limit)
-- LIVE (my Nextcloud instance directory)
--- .htaccess (overwritten with every update)
```

So I added `php_value memory_limit 512M` to the .htaccess in the root-directory but this value is not applied to the LIVE directory.

1. Is what I planned possible?
2. How can I apply the value of the "root"-htaccess to the sub-directory LIVE?

PS: I'm on a shared webspace so I don't have access to the php.ini.

Comment: some hostings allow to put php.ini file to folder where You can define `memory_limit=512M`   but I recommend You to define that limits on app level, for example in config.php or somewhere common `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');` if none of methods and `.htaccess` way not working it means need to talk to hosting support

Comment: @num8er But SHOULD the value of the root-htacces be applied to the sub-dir?

Comment: yes it applies to nested folders